# Linked List error - C

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm just messing around with linked lists but it seems I have many things wrong in my mind. I've tried this with functions and I couldn't get it working. I thought I'd get it right by making it simplier but it still doesn't work. It usually prints just the first element right and then random huge numbers (memory addresses most likely)

I just want to create a list and print its content.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct el{
    int value;
    struct el *next;
};

typedef struct el Elem;



int main()
{
    int nr, i;
    struct el *Head, *Conductor;
    Head = malloc(sizeof(Elem));
    Conductor = Head;
    printf("How many elements do you want to add? ");
    scanf("%d", &nr);
    for(i = 0; i < nr; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter value for element %d:  ", i);
        scanf("%d", &(Conductor->value));
        Conductor = Conductor->next;
        Conductor = malloc(sizeof(Elem));


    }
    free(Conductor->next);
    Conductor->next = NULL;

    Conductor = Head;
    printf("\n");

    for(i = 0; i < nr; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ->  ", Conductor->value);
        Conductor = Conductor->next;
    }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: First allocate memory, then assign the value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should allocate memory for `Conductor->next` before assigning `Conductor->next` to `Conductor`.

```
for(i = 0; i < nr; i++)
{
    printf("Enter value for element %d:  ", i);
    scanf("%d", &(Conductor->value));
    Conductor->next = malloc(sizeof(Elem));
    Conductor = Conductor->next;
}
```

It's important that you make the allocation before the assignment because otherwise the "old" `Conductor->next` will not point to the new `Conductor`.

Answer (score 5):

You do not allocate memory for the `next` pointer.

You need to allocate *before* assigning:

```
scanf("%d", &(Conductor->value));
Conductor->next = malloc(sizeof(Elem));
Conductor = Conductor->next;
```

Comment: I did a mistake while copying the code. Check it now. Is this allocation right?

Comment: @Arlind No, you're doing it in the wrong order, please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

The memory should be allocated to `Conductor->next`,

Change the loop as follows,

```
for(i = 0; i < nr; i++)
{
    printf("Enter value for element %d:  ", i);
    scanf("%d", &(Conductor->value));
    Conductor->next = malloc(sizeof(Elem));
    Conductor = Conductor->next;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Right here:
`Conductor = Conductor->next;`

Conductor is assigned a NULL value, so when you try to dereference it to store input value in the next iteration of the loop you get a segmentation fault.

As others have pointed out you should first allocate memory for `Conductor->next` using `malloc`.

Can I finally recommend that you have a look at a debugger such as [gdb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Debugger) as it makes identifying such problems a breeze?

This is how I found out that there was a problem with `Conductor->next` using gdb:

I stepped through the program until I reached the offending instruction:

```
25    Conductor = Conductor->next;
```

I tried to print what's in `next`:

```
(gdb) print Conductor->next
```

And here's what I got:

```
Cannot access memory at address 0x4
```

Whereas this is what I have in `Conductor`

```
(gdb) print Conductor
$7 = (struct el *) 0x804b008
```

Very easy to see we have a problem as in the next loop it will be assigned an invalid value;